# ArcGIS Online Map Service Source MXD

Tags: arcgis-online, mxd, map-service

Is there any information within a map service regarding the name of the source mxd that was original used to publish/share the data?  Assuming the user shared the data to ArcGIS Online from within ArcMap.

I'd ideally like to use Python and query our services to catalog the various map documents that might have been used to publish/share the service.  This is in support of a data "clean-up" and workflow optimization effort.

Comment: The only things I can think of are common phrases in map document properties like credits, description. Without them ArcGis won't let you share a service

Comment: This might help you out with the metadata you can include with the data you published. https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/share-maps/metadata.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_CE02409EE61D4A51A2BB943A2D8D982F